# How to make empty space in URL be readable by passing json URL

Tags: java, android, json, url

```
> String url = "http://localhost:61819/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/empty url";
```

how to remove empty space while passing url.

Comment: Just leave the "empty url" out? String url = "http://localhost:61819/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/";

Comment: Replace the space with `%20`. For more info see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: does not replacing space with %20 solves the problem ?

Comment: use this url encoding : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String url = "http://localhost:61819/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/empty url".replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

(or)

```
  String url=URLEncoder.encode("http://localhost:61819/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/empty url", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: if string object pass through URL means,the string object which contain space means

Comment: just use like url.replaceAll(" ","%20"); above code url is string object!

Comment: I dont know why u have accepted this answer!! This answer gives the solution for this instant only. But u have to consider all the scenarios while Unit Testing. What will u do if there is any space in `http://localhost:61819/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/` . From above answer, if there is `space` in this `url`, then it is also replaced.

Comment: @AvadhaniY yes it's replace with url encode value space for %20 will be reaplaced!

Comment: @AvadhaniY yes encode is best way now i am update my answer ok!

Comment: @AvadhaniY i tried this url encode but having error Unhandeled Exception java:io:UnsupportedEncodeingException...

Answer (score 3):

try this class

```
import java.net.UrlEncoder;
String newUrl = URLEncoder.encode(oldUrl);
```

Comment: if string object pass through URL means,the string object which contain space means

Comment: `oldUrl` is your orignal String, and the `newUrl` is the result after encoding your String.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good way to replace the spaces in url. It may change the url.

Instead, I'd prefer to encode the url by using `URLEncoder.encode()` method. 
That way, the spaces and also the special characters will be handled accordingly.

In a J2EE application, if you are sending a url as a response then you should use `encodeRedirectUrl()` method of HttpServletResponse.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer Encoding than Pattern Matching. Just encode the String as below:

```
String url = "http://localhost:61819/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/empty url";
       url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can check All Unicode URL [From this Site](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp)!

for space just use:-

```
URI uri = new URI(string.replace(" ", "%20"));
```